# error build: Value of type 'UIDragInteraction' has no member 'previewForLifting'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm trying to learn to put my web dev skills to use in iOS. Not understanding how to add members to UIDragInteraction.

Seeing this error:

> error build: Value of type 'UIDragInteraction' has no member 'previewForLifting'

My code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

class DragDelegate: NSObject, UIDragInteractionDelegate {
    func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let webView = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is WKWebView }) as? WKWebView
        let provider = NSItemProvider(object: webView?.url?.absoluteString as NSString? ?? "")
        let item = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
        return [item]
    }
}

struct BPMNView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let urlString = "https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/dfceec6a/starter/diagram.bpmn"

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!))
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("BPMN Diagram")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
            BPMNView()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .onAppear {
                    if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                        let view = windowScene.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view {
                        let preview = UITargetedPreview(view: view)
                        let interaction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: DragDelegate())
                        view.addInteraction(interaction)
                        interaction.isEnabled = true
                        interaction.previewForLifting = preview

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm so new to this I'm not understanding the logic. I also can't get the screen to show the content when I take out `interaction.previewForLifting = preview`:

[image]

Comment: There is no `previewForLifting` property on `UIDragInteraction`. But there is the `dragInteraction(_:previewForLifting:session:)` delegate method. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

„has no member 'previewForLifting'“ is compiler speak for telling the programmer that this method or property does not exist in the class.

Have a look at:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidraginteractiondelegate/2891057-draginteraction/

UIDragInteraction on its own has very little public interface, which is covered completely here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidraginteraction/

Apple's documentation often lacks explanation, but technically it is usually pretty complete.

As was already pointed out, this is a delegate method, not an instance property. The role of the delegate in drag & drop handling is rather critical to understand, as it is used for a lot of interaction handling inside iOS.